# How to populate default date using my-date-picker

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am using my-date-picker . How to populate the date field with default date( default date I am getting from service) . I am using the below code that returns outOldestDate from service. I am trying to set that as default date in onInit function. But the date doesnt get populated.

```
 <my-date-picker name="outOldestDate" class="form-control required" placeholder="Oldest" [options]="myDatePickerOptions formControlName="outOldestDate"></my-date-picker>

public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    // other options...
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
};


    ngOnInit() {
        this.accountReceivableForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          outOldestDate: [null, Validators.required]
        });
this.getDate();
}


getDate(): void {
//service call happens here
 resultArray => {
        this.ng4LoadingSpinnerService.hide();
        console.log(resultArray);
        this.ARHospitalListData = resultArray;
        this.outOldestDate = this.ARHospitalListData.dischargeDate.fromDate;

}

}
```

Comment: The documentation at https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker lists simple ways to instantiate the datepicker with a date. Can you edit your question to tell us why these ways don't work?

Comment: @NicoHaase The documentation lists ways to hardcode  date . But in my case, I am getting the date from service response and I need to set that to default date. As you see in the above code, all the response values are stored in resultArray which has fromDate. Now i need to set that fromDate value as a default date to Oldest date field

Comment: @NicoHaase Can you help me on this ? I am trying this for a long time

Answer (score 1):

```
 this.outOldestDate = { formatted: this.ARHospitalListData.dischargeDate.fromDate };
```

Adding formatted resolved the issue